# Microstrategy - creating a simple percentage column

Tags: percentage, microstrategy, metric

I have a metric that shows sum(Widgets). I want to find out the number of Widgets that were faulty, so I created another metric with that. I now want to find the % faulty from total, and have created a widget for the % calculation, however it will not show anything other than 0.00% Whether there are values or not.

Definition in Metric Editor:

([Number of Faulty Widgets] / [Number of Widgets])

I've been all over Microstrategy community and have tried possible solutions/formatting etc. all to no avail. I've looked at % column settings in other % metrics in our projects and can't see any difference in settings or the way it is formulated.

Can anyone helps me try to figure out why I am only getting 0%?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning on the Allow Smart Metric on the Subtotals tabs, if that is set on, I would try experimenting with the dynamic aggregation function.

Comment: Explain please.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a metric there are two tabs (in developer/desktop), on the first tab you enter the formula for the metric, on the second page you can set what formulas to use for aggregation, (i.e. if the report combines several records, do you want it to add the metric values or show the highest value), now the smart metrix is a tick box and is only available if there is more than 1 metric and changes how the sql sums up values (i.e. sum(Metric1) * Sum(Metric2) or sum(Metric1 * Metric2), for example if you have 2 rows Metric 1 = 2 and 4 and Metric 2 = 3 and 6, one will calculate to 16 and another will calculate to 18.